# Maven Plugin - mvn release:prepare

Tags: maven-2, maven, maven-plugin, maven-3, maven-release-plugin

Hi i'm checking via new created plugin (mpc) some parts of the pom (scm area)...but now i faced that during the mvn release:prepare of a different modules which uses the created plugin (mpc) I got the following messages:

```
[INFO] [INFO] Scanning the projects...
[INFO] [INFO] ...
[INFO] [INFO] not a working copy....
```

The output "not a working copy" ...is because I'm checking the svn info output...
The question is can I recogdnize this state during the mvn release:prepare somehow ? for example via roperties or checking an attribute of the current project ? Which means in other words that I know inside my maven plugin (mpc) that currently the release:prepare cycle is running?

Comment: I found a solution. I simply check if the current build is building an SNAPSHOT version or not (ArtifactUtil.isSnapshot() very helpfull).

Comment: Post your solution as an answer and chose it as the best answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution. I simply check if the current build is building an SNAPSHOT version or not (ArtifactUtil.isSnapshot() very helpfull).